# Association not creating methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have User, Guide, and CityObj models. User has one Guide, and Guide belongs to User. This allows me to use methods to access the parent from the child and vice versa:

```
a_user.guide
a_guide.user
```

But these methods aren't there for CityObj:

```
a_guide.cityobj ----> error
a_cityobj.guide ----> error
```

Maybe it has to do with the camel case? It seems like I'm doing the same thing for User/Guide and Guide/CityObj.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :guide, dependent: :destroy

  ...

end
```

Guide.rb

```
class Guide < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cityObj, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user

  ...
end
```

CityObj.rb

```
class CityObj < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guide
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per convention, you should use ***snake case***

```
a_guide.cityobj
a_cityobj.guide
```

should be

```
a_guide.city_obj
a_city_obj.guide
```

Also, change your association in `guide.rb` model to below.

```
#guide.rb
has_one :city_obj, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: But what should it be in the model?

Comment: @Terrytreks Which model?

Comment: Shouldn't the association create a build method, like a_city.build?

Comment: @Terrytreks You really have to look these Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

As @Pavan said the convention should be snake case, including for the filenames and the association definition (and methods in general)

- CitObj.rb should be city_obj.rb
- User.rb should be user.rb

Also :

```
class Guide < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :city_obj, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user

  # ...
end
```

This will "generate" association methods like : `build_city_obj` etc...